# Error while invoking Ant target from Jenkins

Tags: java, ant, jenkins

I am configuring the Jenkins build for my project, we use ant as build tools. The build is working fine in my local system, when I try to invoke it from Jenkins hosted in linux server I am getting the below error, Could you please let me know why this error is occurring in Jenkins.

```
/opt/app/TSET/master/build.xml:7: The following error occurred while    executing this line:
/opt/app/TEST/mymodule/revbuild.xml:78: java.lang.SecurityException: class    "com.sun.xml.bind.ContextFactory"'s signer information does not match signer     information of other classes in the same package
at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(ClassLoader.java:806)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:487)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:625)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:295)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.safeLoadClass(ContextFinder.java:481)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:113)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:249)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:372)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:337)
at atg.appassembly.util.MetaInfGeneratorImpl.loadApplicationXml13FromStream(MetaInfGeneratorImpl.java:438)
at atg.appassembly.EarInfoFactory.getJ2EEModulesForEar(EarInfoFactory.java:292)
at atg.appassembly.EarInfoFactory.processEARModules(EarInfoFactory.java:235)
at atg.appassembly.EarInfoFactory.createEarInfo(EarInfoFactory.java:143)
at atg.appassembly.ApplicationAssembler.getEarInfoFromDynModules(ApplicationAssembler.java:273)
at atg.appassembly.ant.CreateUnpackedEarTask.execute(CreateUnpackedEarTask.java:479)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:441)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the keystore on your local PC, and the keystore used by jenkins.
My first guess is that you're missing some certs on Jenkins which are installed in the keystore on your PC